# imagettftext cannot open font file

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagettftext

Using the [example from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) I get a warning, and the image is not rendered correctly. I supply a full path to the .ttf file like so: `/var/www/public/myfont.ttf`

```
PHP Warning:  imagettftext() [<a href='function.imagettftext'>function.imagettftext</a>]: Could not find/open font in <phpfile>
```

I am using a custom .ttf font found [here](http://www.1001fonts.com/search.html?query=Unmasked%20BB). I can open the file fine in Ubuntu as a valid font file. I also attempted other fonts, with the same result.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 32 bit, with apache2, php5, freetype6 and php5-gd installed. I also attempted to chmod 777 file and folder with ttf file, with the same result.

How can I get the example working using a custom ttf font file?

*Edit: The code I'm using:

```
<?php
// File is: /var/www/public/test.php
// Apart from $font variable, it's copy-pasted from php.net

// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = '/var/www/public/UnmaskedBB.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Output from phpinfo();

```
[gd]
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  2.0
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.3.11
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version     6b
PNG Support     enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.42
WBMP Support    enabled
```

Testing `is_file` and `is_readable`:

```
$font = realpath('./').'/UnmaskedBB.ttf';
echo "Font: ".$font; // /var/www/public/UnmaskedBB.ttf
echo "Is file? ".is_file($font); // 1
echo "Is readable? ".is_readable($font); // 1
```

Comment: Can you show the exact code?  I can't see anything wrong but for completeness' sake

Comment: Are you 100% sure that is the font's exact path? Taking into account case sensitivity?

Comment: And there seems to be a typo: `tff`

Comment: Yes. Initially I stumbled on the problem using PHPThumb `wmt` filter, with PHPThumb verifying that the font file exists and can be read before calling imagettftext. I might add that imagettfbox gives the same error. Is there any other good way to debug what's going on here?

Comment: @Jon strange. What do `is_readable()` or `is_file()` return?

Comment: What version is your GD library ?

Comment: Can you try with a tried-and-true font like `Arial.ttf`?

Comment: Using arial.ttf from: http://alxr.usatlas.bnl.gov/lxr/source/atlas/Tools/AtlasDoxygen/fonts/ttf/arial.ttf gave the same result with warning could not open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading distro, including all php packages solved the issue

Answer (score 8):

You could try to insert:

```
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
```

in front of the first `imagettftext`, just to make sure it is no path issue.

**UPDATE**

In case you are using font caches like `fc-cache`, don't forget to refresh it, e.g.:

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Comment: This gives the same result unfortunately. But in any case I'm using a static font file, not a built in one.

Comment: had the same problem and it workt on my distro (Ubuntu 11.10)

Comment: This worked for me: putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
Am using Ubuntu 12.04 server and it fixed the problem of imagettftext(): Could not find/open font error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the ttf file in the same dir as your php file and change **$font** to

```
$font = 'UnmaskedBB.ttf';
```

Comment: It's already in the same directory, and I assume you mean 'UnmaskedBB' without the .ttf since there's no leading `/` in place? In any case - the same warning is present

Comment: Yes I mean that, as you assume... Can you try to update your GD library - mine is bundled (2.0.34 compatible) and works ok.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Note: This function is only available if PHP is compiled with freetype support (--with-freetype-dir=DIR)

sudo apt-get install freetype*